# How to execute a command line in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, execution

I have problem executing a command line in C#:

[image: Screenshot]

I try:

```
String Mon_CMD=@"C:\Windows\system32>ConsoleTest.exe --asMRZ C:\temp\TEST_CMD\image.jpg C:\temp\TEST_CMD\";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/C ' Mon_CMD'");
```

But I always get an error.

How can I execute this exact command?

Comment: You are not really concatenating the strings, it's wrong c# syntax, try: `Process.Start("cmd.exe", $"/C '{Mon_CMD}'");` or `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C '" + Mon_CMD + "'");`

Comment: You don't start CMD to execute a command from there, you start "ConsoleTest.exe" directly with the parameters required. Besides your string is not well formatted

Answer (score 1):

Provided ConsoleTest.exe is in C:\Windows\system32 (which does not seem a good idea but that's another topic)

```
String Mon_CMD = @"C:\Windows\system32\ConsoleTest.exe";
String arguments = @"--asMRZ C:\temp\TEST_CMD\image.jpg C:\temp\TEST_CMD\";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Mon_CMD, arguments);
```

Should do the job

And as suggested by cFrozenDeath and Nyerguds, if you want to use Mon_CMD in another string, you have several options such as: build a new string using the + operator, StringBuilder or if you are on C#6 string interpolation:

```
string arguments = $"/C ' {Mon_CMD}'";
```

(and you don't need a verbatim string for that one)

Comment: You should also mention the incorrect attempt to concatenate strings by the OP, which is the wrong part in the code

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Do you mean combining Path and exe name in Mon_CMD or in the arguments?

Comment: @vc74 The fact they put the text "Mon_CMD" inside a quoted string instead of referencing it as variable.

Comment: None, I mean the OP's attempt (`"/C ' Mon_CMD'"`) which should have been `"/C '" + Mon_CMD + "'"` (what @Nyerguds said)